# apache2 mod_proxy pass PHPSESSID content to private server

Tags: php, apache, session, mod-proxy

I have probably very basic question, but I was unable to find how mod_proxy exactly works when dealing with PHPSESSIDs

I have very simple setup:

```
ProxyPass /public-server-proxy http://192.168.1.1:80/my-dir
ProxyPassReverse /public-server-proxy http://192.168.1.1:80/my-dir
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  /public-server-proxy /
```

**My scenario:** I perform login via public-server and var $_SESSION['user_logged'] get set to "1"

Now I would need to access file verify.php at private-server 192.168.1.1 that also needs to check if var $_SESSION['user_logged'] is 1..

It looks that var $_SESSION['user_logged'] is empty on private server.

Is mod_proxy also responsible to pass $_SESSION and its data from public server to private one?

Comment: The session only exists on the server it's created at. To pass data to the private server you need to send it from the public server. `PHPSESSID` just contains the session ID that corresponds to the session on that server

Comment: Yes, thats is correct. PHPSESSID identifiers are the same on both private and public server, however with different content. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: If you can share a database or some other resource (e.g. a cache?) you can just use that to send data around.